# Windows Phone prohibit textboxes focus getting

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have four textboxes and 10 buttons for digits. I need to change
background of textboxes when one of four is focused. But when i click
on button there i loose textbox focus and background return to normal
(from focused visual state). So how can i prohibit buttons to catch focus when i clicked 
them and save focus on textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using numbers on your buttons?  If so, is there a specific reason that you're making your own number pad?  If it is just because you want to have a number pad instead of the regular keyboard, are you aware that you can add this property to your textboxes InputScope="TelephoneNumber" which will give you a number pad similar to the telephone dialing pad.